# Grails hashmap variable in javascript gives different format

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy

In my grails controller:

```
 assert result == [hus:['hus@gmail.com', 'SE', 'on', '9908899876'], vin:['vin@gmail.com', 'SD', 'on', '7765666543']]
println "result is::"+result
println result.getClass() 

    [result:result]  //passing model to view
```

which prints :

```
[hus:[hus@gmail.com, SE, on, 9908899876], vin:[vin@gmail.com, SD, on, 7765666543]]
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

but when i get this hashmap from my view page and access from javascript

```
 $(function(){
    alert('${result}');
});
```

it prints

```
 {
  hus=[hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542],
  vin = [vin@gmail.com, SE,887654433]
  }
```

which is not valid object ,  is not a valid object, (`: replaced by =)` it should be

```
{ hus:[hus@gmail.com,SE,9902766542], vin : [vin@gmail.com, SE,887654433] }
```

why it is so? how do i correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current output is produced by `toString()` of the `Map` `result` which can be used to 
print the data but is not very useful to transfer it to javascript.

You should convert the result to json in your controller:

```
def json = result as JSON
```

and return it to your model:

```
[json : json ]
```

After that you can create an object in Javascript using [JQery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON("${ json.toString() }");
```

Comment: And then parse it as json in the javascript

Comment: Can u tell me how to parse it as json in the javascript?